Problems with my sound editor
I tried to update Ocenaudio, but it wouldn't update. I even tried getting a older version, but it did the same thing. I keep getting this message as I try to open Ocenaudio.
Ocenaudio exe

The procedure entry point
D3D12SerializeVersionedRootSignature could not be located in
the dynamic link library C:\Program Files\ocenaudio\Qt6Gui.dll.

The procedure entry point GetSystemMetricsForDpi could not be
located in the dunamic link library C:\Program Files\ocenaudio\Qt6Gui.dll.

